# How to specify to rjags to run hierarchical model with multiple conditions

Tags: r, regression, bayesian, jags

I'm trying to run a Bayesian regression model using rjags, and my data have 4 relevant conditions. The model runs fine when collapsing across conditions, however I don't understand where/how to specify that I want this model to run separately for each condition, yet still give me a `coda.samples` output that allows me to compare Beta values (I would like 4 Beta0 and 4 Beta1 values, one for each condition). Here's my model:

```
    order_model <-
    "model {
beta_0 ~ dnorm(0, .0000001)
beta_1 ~ dnorm(0, .0000001)
sigma ~ dunif(0, 100)
sigma_u0 ~ dunif(0,100)
sigma_u1 ~ dunif(0,100)
sigma_i0 ~ dunif(0,100)


for (i in 1:num_items) {
  w_0i[i] ~ dnorm(0, 1/sigma_i0^2)
}

for (i in 1:num_subj+1) {
  u_0s[i] ~ dnorm(0, 1 / sigma_u0^2)
  u_1s[i] ~ dnorm(0, 1 / sigma_u1^2)
}
for (i in 1:length(rt)) {
  rt[i] ~ dnorm((beta_0 + w_0i[item[i]] + u_0s[subject[i]]) + (beta_1 + u_1s[subject[i]]) * order[i], 1/sigma^2)
}
}"
```

Where subject and item are referred to to get fixed effect offsets, and "rt" is a continuous dependent variable. Condition is coded in a vector "condition" with values 1:4.

I assume I need another for loop somewhere, but I'm not sure where.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When asking a question, saying excuses about how new you are to the topic is a bad idea: 1) it is always irrelevant to the question; 2) it makes a question harder to read, because those excuses are just additional text people have to read to understand the question. There is nothing terribly wrong with that, many people on SO do that, but they certainly shouldn't. For the sake of better questions : )

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to index beta_0 and beta_1 using condition like so:

```
  rt[i] ~ dnorm((beta_0[condition[i]] + w_0i[item[i]] + u_0s[subject[i]]) + (beta_1[condition[i]] + u_1s[subject[i]]) * order[i], 1/sigma^2)
```

[Or maybe beta_0[condition[subject[i]] depending on how the data is structured]

And:

```
  for(c in 1:4){
       beta_0[c] ~ dnorm(0, .0000001)
       beta_1[c] ~ dnorm(0, .0000001)
  }
```

You can then monitor the 4 values of beta_0 and beta_1 and compare them using the output from JAGS - either compare the credible intervals, or do pairwise comparisons by subtracting one level away from another and then look at the credible intervals for the difference.

Matt